# Same Django unit test fails sometimes and succeeds at other times

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have the following Django unit test:

```
def test_highscores_no_n_success_(self):
    """Checks that top 10 highscores of an owner are returned,
    if no number of highscores is specified in the request"""
    high_score = 100
    for users in range(15):
        user = create_user(1, 1, "aguha")
        user.high_score = high_score
        user.save()
        high_score +=10
    response = self.client.get('/api/highscores/', 
                                {'token': 1, 'key': 1})
    self.assertContains(response, 
                        "\"id\": 10, \"high_score\": 180")
```

For the following function:

```
def highscores(request):
    """Returns the top n (or 10) high scores for an owner"""
    r = request.GET
    token = r['token']
    owner = Owner.objects.get(api_token=token)
    try:
        n = r['n']
    except KeyError:
        user_count = User.objects.filter(owner=owner).count()
        if user_count >= 10:
            n = 10
        else:
            n = user_count
    top_scorers = User.objects.filter(owner=owner).order_by('-high_score').values('id', 'high_score')[:n]
    top_scorers_json = json.dumps(list(top_scorers))
    return HttpResponse(top_scorers_json,
                    content_type="application/json")
```

This is the `create_user` function:

```
def create_user(token, key, owner_username):
    """Creates a user object for the purpose of testing"""
    try:
        owner = Owner.objects.get(api_token=token)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        owner = Owner.objects.create(api_token=token, api_key=key, 
                                    username=owner_username)
    return User.objects.create(owner=owner)
```

Weirdly enough, this test sometimes succeeds, and fails at other times. When it fails it says it can't find `"id": 10, "high_score": 180` in the response. How is this possible? The database is reset for each new test and erased after the tests are complete, so that shouldn't be an issue. What's the problem here?

My original hypothesis was that it may have something to do with the time between running tests. But that doesn't seem to have an effect. I can run it several times one after the other and it'll work okay. Then I come back and run many minutes later and it fails. Is something wrong with my function or with my test?

Comment: Where are you setting the `owner` value for the newly-created Users?

Comment: In the `create_user` function, the three arguments are `token`, `key` and `username`, and these three specify the `owner`. It first checks if the owner with the given values exists; if not, it creates a new owner and assigns the user to the owner.

Comment: So you probably need to post the code of that function. Your use of "key" makes me wonder if you are using literal values for primary keys there, which is not guaranteed to succeed: sequences aren't usually reset between tests.

Comment: I added the function. Here, the key is not primary key; it's a special field in the `Owner` model to identify the owners. It's a CharField and not an AutoField.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I was getting the error. In the list that was being returned, sometimes `id` was appearing before `high_score`, i.e. I was getting `"id": 10, "high_score": 180`, which is why the test ran OK. But at other times `high_score` was appearing before `id`, i.e. it was `"high_score": 180, "id": 10`, which is why the test was failing.